# Why do we need a buffer when we get input from the user?

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

Why do we need a buffer when we get input from the user?

For example:

```
chat arr[10];
cin>>arr;
// or
cin.get(arr,10);
```

I read that there is a temporary variable called buffer that stores the input that the user typed. So:

1. Does the compiler use the buffer just in case of char array? If the answer is "no" then when does it get used?
2. What is the reason that the compiler uses buffer in my example above?
3. If the buffer in my example above is an array, how the compiler choose its size?

Comment: C++ has a `string` type, which you should probably use instead. It isn't the compiler using the buffer, it's *you*, the programmer. Same deal with choosing a size—that's your responsibility when you write the code. Using a string type solves these problems and more.

Comment: @CodyGray : I know the using std::string is the easy way to go. Im just trying to understand how the compiler does this. If you have an anwser to my question.I'll preciate it. thanks

Comment: "I read that there is a temporary variable called buffer" is not quite true. There is only a variable caller `buffer` if you make a variable with that name! Now the system may use buffers for all its in- and output, but you as a lowly console application aren't allowed near those.

Comment: @MrLister I'm not sure that the OP's native language is English.  I think he meant that there is a temporary variable called _a_ buffer; that he's asking about the buffering going on behind the scenes when inputting from `cin` (or any other `istream`).

Comment: @JamesKanze yes that's what I meant. is the same buffer variable get used when I use cin in my program. because sometimes when I use cin.getline function it get ignored because the buffer has already a "delimeter" '\n'.

Comment: @AlexDan The intermediate buffers are never ignored.  You can't physically read from a disk up until the next `\n`, and at least in the usual OS's, you can't specifically read from the OS until the next `\n`.  (In fact, at least with Unix and Windows, when the "file" is actually a keyboard, the `read` request will read until either the requested number of characters __or__ a new line is entered.  Redirect the input from a file, however, and the read will not stop at a newline character.)

Comment: @JamesKanze for example cin>>var; //...// cin.getline(array,10); in this example cin.getline will be ignored because the buffer start with '\n' from cin>>var; which didn't get extracted . so this is why I asked why is the same buffer is used for to get the user input in my all program

Comment: @AlexDan That has nothing to do with buffering.  A stream is a sequence of characters, which are extracted one after the other.  `cin >> var` will not extract any trailing white space, so it will be there for the next request to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several intermediate buffers involved, for various reasons:

1. The OS has an internal buffer.  This depends somewhat on the input
   device: the physical reads from a disk are by sector, so a buffer which
   is a multiple of the sector size must be used; keyboard input is
   normally buffered up until a newline character, to allow a limited
   degree of editing (backspace, etc.); and so on.  This is mostly 
   transparent to the application, although it does mean that even when
   reading just a single character, the read won't return until the user
   inputs a newline.
2. The streambuf used by the istream has a buffer.  This is done to
   reduce the number of requests to the OS.  The size of this buffer will
   generally depend on the type of streambuf; a `filebuf` will normally be
   optimized for the platform file IO—big enough to effectively
   reduce requests, but not so big as to induce paging.  On some systems,
   with some types of files, it's possible that the `filebuf` replaces its
   buffer with a memory mapping of the file.

The streambuf has functions which allow modifying its buffer management
somewhat.  It's very rare that they should be used, however; the authors
of the library have generally done a good enough job that you can't
easily improve on it.

With regards to the `>>` operator: this buffering all occurs at a lower
level.  The `>>` operator (and indeed all input from an `istream`)
forwards requests for individual characters, or arrays of characters, to
the streambuf.  This decoupling of actual input of characters from the
parsing of them is fundamental to the design of `istream`: `istream`
takes care of the parsing only; it contains a pointer to a streambuf
which takes care of the actual input.  (Some of the parsing functions
may also contain buffers.  For example, `>>` of an `int` may collect the
sequence of digits in a buffer before starting actual conversion.)

Answer (score 1):

There has to be some place for the input (data collected from the outside) to be stored.  Lacking this, it is hard to understand *why* the input would be done at all.

Even for other data types—most clearly numbers held in `int`, `long`, and `float` (known as *scalar types*)—there has to be a variable declared which allocates storage sufficient to store the result:

```
long  n;
double  d;
cin >> n;
cin >> d;
```

The compiler does not choose its size.  You have to declare it; it is generally okay to make it too big, but making it too small can cause several kinds of problems.

Comment: where is the buffer in your example. I dont think there is a need for the buffer in your example. I thought using the buffer when the input is char array (in my example) is the extracts chars that came after the delimeter. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @AlexDan:  behind the scenes are several layers of buffers which exist to improve system performance and efficiency.  Some of them can be explicitly switched off (if you know what you are doing), but the default handling is usually what you want.  Buffering is performed by the C++ runtime library, by the operating system, and by the device driver(s).

Comment: for example sometimes cin.getline funtction get ignored becasue the buffer has already a delimeter '\n' inside it which didn't  get extracted. so where the buffer exactly belong to. is it global or static member of istream. thanks